# Read nth element of a large json file

Tags: json, r

I have a large number of 35MB json files (one per hour for two years) - they are recordings from a meteorological station with one record each 5 seconds (720/h). They take about 45s to import into R, but I would like to be able to run through them and extract a single record.

Here is an example:

```
library(jsonlite)

x <- list(one = list(b = 0.1, c = 0.3),
          two = list(b = 0.2, c = 0.2))
y <- toJSON(x)
setwd(tempdir())
writeLines(y, 'foo.json')
```

From the file `foo.json`, I would like to be able to just read in element one or element 1 b

For those interested in a non-trival case, in this file from [Jan 5 2018 is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzzn13e77bz5k8y/2018-01-05_16-40-48_environmentlogger.json?dl=0), I want to import the *n*th element named 'spectrum'.

Comment: Anyway you might be able to change the source to limit the data source.  I am sure it's a bit obvious that this is a tedious task.  You'll still need to parse out the entire file looking for the one value by itself.  At 1 and hour for ... sounds like fun.  I would definitely try the source, see if they can modify the source or create a new output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a system JSON parser, and control it through `?system` commands.

For example, I like `jq` (for which there is also an R pacakge, if you're interested, called `jqr`)

```
## install jq from 
## https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/

## print the result of extracting 'one'
curlString <- paste0("cat '", tempdir(), "/foo.json' | jq -r '.one'")
system(curlString)
# {
#   "b": [
#       0.1
#       ],
#   "c": [
#       0.3
#       ]
# }

## return the result of extracting 'one.b' to R
curlString <- paste0("cat '", tempdir(), "/foo.json' | jq -r '.one.b'")
res <- system(curlString, intern = T)
paste0(res, collapse = "")
# "[  0.1]"
```